# Simplification (algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem states just to simplify:
$$
\frac{(x+1)^2(x-2)-(x+1)(x-2)^2}{(x-2)^3}
$$
I was given the answer as $3(x+1)/(x-2)^2$, but every time I try to work it out I get a different answer.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I just cancelled the bottom (x-2)^3 with the (x-2)^2 and (x-2) in the numerator. That got me [(x+1)^2]-(x+1)

Comment: @JamesC. But in the numerator, you have only $(x-2)$, not $(x-2)^3$ as in the denominator.

Comment: The fact is that you cannot simplify factors inside a sum, but only if the numerator is a product

Comment: So I need to open up each factor?

Comment: Either that or you could use the inverse of the distributive property and "collect" (x-2) above

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One more way. For simplicity denote $a=x+1$, $b=x-2$. Hence your expression is 
$$
\frac{a^2 b - a b^2}{b^3}
$$
In the numerator both $a$ and $b$ repeat, so you can pull them out:
$$
\frac{ab(a-b)}{b^3}
$$
and then notice the cancellation in the brackets and in the numerator and denominator to get 
$$
\frac{3a}{b^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\require{\cancel}$

$$\begin{align}\frac{(x+1)^2(x-2)-(x+1)(x-2)^2}{(x-2)^3} & = \frac{(x+1)^2(\cancel{x-2})-(x+1)(\cancel{x - 2})(x-2)}{(\cancel{x - 2})(x-2)^2} \\ \\
& = \frac{(x+1)[(x +1) - (x - 2)]}{(x - 2)^2}\\ \\ 
& = \frac{3(x+1)}{(x - 2)^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for the cancel package. Did you notice, BTW, that the author said it was his opinion that his package should never be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you divide numerator and denomimator by $x-2$ you get in the numerator $(x+1)^2-(x+1)(x-2)=x^2+2x+1-x^2+x+2=3(x+1)$